# How to get value of javascript variable in python variable in Python-CGI script

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi

I want to take the value of javascript variable into python variable.

This is Python-CGI script which displays a selection box and selected value appears on the page. But I want to take selected value in python variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 -u
import time, sys, os

# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb

sys.stdout.write('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n')
print "\n\n"
print "<html>"
print "<body>"

rows = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']
print "<script>"
print "function showData() {"
print "var sel = document.getElementById('combo');"
print "var value = sel.value;"
print "var text = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;"
print "document.getElementById('secondP').innerHTML=text;}"
print "</script>"

print '<form name="comboform">'
print '<select name="comboselect" onchange="showData()" id="combo">'
for row in rows:
    print "<option value='%s'>%s</option>"%(row,row)
print "</select>"
print "</form>"

print '<p id="secondP">&nbsp;</p>'

# HERE I WANT TO TAKE VALUE OF SELECTED IP ADDRESS (var value) IN PYTHON VARIABLE
# selected_ip_adr = value #something like this where value has selected ip address
# NEED TO PASS THE SAME TO ANOTHER SCRIPT

sys.stdout.flush()
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

It would be great if someone can suggest a work-around to achieve this.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client, CGI runs on the server.

Comment: @ Barmar, does that mean that there is no way to get this javascript variable value in python variable?

Comment: You can use AJAX to send it to another script.

Comment: FYI, `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value` can be simplified to just `sel.value`.

Comment: And you never set the variable `text`.

Comment: When you submit the form, the selected IP will be in `cgi.FieldStorage['comboselect']`

Comment: I haven't kept submit button to avoid multiple pages. Edited the question with your suggested changes.

Comment: If you don't want to reload the page, you need to use AJAX.

Comment: I am not aware of AJAX, can you please guide me further on how can I do this with AJAX? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it with following code and multiple pages:

```
# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
op = form.getvalue('combo')
```